# DEBUG_FRAME log messages in catalina.out after starting tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, log4j2, apache-axis

I am using axis2 version 1.8.2 for web services and tomcat server. After starting tomcat, my catalina.out is getting flooded with DEBUG_FRAME log messages even though logj2.xml is set for info. This is how my webapp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>

        <!-- Add more loggers as needed -->
        <Logger name="org.apache.axis2" level="ERROR"/>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And this is what DEBUG_FRAME logs in catalina.out are looking like.

```
[2023-09-08T10:02:34,006]DEBUG[main] - DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString(JavaUtils.java:564)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.mapActionToOperation(AxisService.java:878)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:378)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceGroupBuilder.populateServiceGroup(ServiceGroupBuilder.java:101)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:117)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:232)
```

This issue appeared in version 1.8.0 (I am not sure it was related to DEBUG_FRAME) but there is a ticket where a bug was reported in 1.8.0 version for unnecessary debug logs. It was fixed in 1.8.2. [Link to ticket raised for the bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-6013)
Is axis2 using some different loggers? Can someone please explain here from where exactly these DEBUG_FRAME logs are coming in catlaina.out?

Thanks.

I changed the root level from info to error and configuration status from debug to WARN.
But still there is no change in the logs. I tried with the default configuration of axis2 version 1.8.2, still there are DEBUG_FRAME logs in catalina.out. I expected that axis2 uses the default logging configuration in axis2 directory. But looks like this is not the case.